# Как правильно переводить единицы измерения на лету?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую jQuery. У меня есть несколько инпутов с единицами измерения массы. Я хочу при вводе в любом из инпутов, автоматически считать и выводить в значение инпутов результат.
Например ввёл в инпут с килограммами цифру 1, а он сразу посчитал для всех других единиц сколько будет 1 кг в этих единицах.
Сам функционал работает как надо, но вот не пойму, почему с некоторыми единицами идут не правильные расчёты, вернее не пойму как сделать, чтобы работало правильно.

Например если ввожу 1 кг, то для грамм, центнеров и для тонн он показывается правильное значение, а для килотонны он показывает 1000000, но 1 кг не равен такого количеству килотонн.
Или ввожу 1 Миллиграмм он мне считает это как 1 тонну и т.д.

Не пойму как правильно настроить расчёты в зависимости от того, в какой инпут что ввели. Помогите пожалуйста решить.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const conversionFactors = {
        "Килограммы": 1,
        "Граммы": 1000,
        "Тонны": 0.001,
        "Центнер": 0.01,
        "Миллиграмм": 1000000,
        "Сантиграмм": 10000,
        "Микрограмм": 1000000000,
        "Килотонна": 1000000,
        "Ньютон на Земле": 9.81,
        "Карат": 5000,
        "Атомная масса": 1.66e-27 * 1000,
        "Фунт": 2.20462,
        "Унция": 35.274,
        "Гран": 15432.4,
        "Стоун": 0.157473,
    };

    function updateUnitValues(sourceElement, sourceValue) {
        const parentRow = sourceElement.closest(".row.align-items-center");
        const sourceLabel = parentRow.find(".custom-label").text();

        const conversionFactor = conversionFactors[sourceLabel];
        if (typeof conversionFactor === "undefined") {
            $("input[type='text']").val("0");
            return;
        }
        const weightValue = sourceValue * (1 / conversionFactor);

        $("input[type='text']").each(function () {
            const targetLabel = $(this).closest(".row.align-items-center").find(".custom-label").text();
            const targetConversionFactor = conversionFactors[targetLabel];
            if (typeof targetConversionFactor === "undefined") {
                $(this).val("0");
            } else {
                const targetValue = weightValue * targetConversionFactor;
                $(this).val(targetValue.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,15})?/)[0]);
            }
        });
    }

    $("input[type='text']").on("input", function () {
        const sourceValue = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(",", "."));
        if (!isNaN(sourceValue)) {
            updateUnitValues($(this), sourceValue);
        } else {
            $("input[type='text']").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: У тебя все данные указаны "относительно килограмма", он у тебя является "единицей". Отсюда - нужно знать что же поменяли, перевести это в килограммы, записать в это в поле и потом пересчитать все поля "относительно значения в килограммах". Само измененное поле можно не менять, дабы не попасть на округление значения.

Comment: В твоем объекте `Килотонна` записана не верно. Не `1000000`, а `1e-6`, т.е. `0.000001`.

Comment: Вот это `"Атомная масса": 1.66e-27 * 1000` можно заменить на `"Атомная масса": 1.66e-24`.

Comment: @ksa можете показать пример, не могу понять как это сделать уже несколько дней

Answer (score 2):

> можете показать пример, не могу понять как это сделать уже несколько дней

Выше я предлагал вот такой вариант реализации.

Так же обрати внимание на значение `Килотонна` и `Атомная масса`/

```js
const obj = {
    "Килограммы": 1,
    "Граммы": 1000,
    "Тонны": 0.001,
    "Центнер": 0.01,
    "Миллиграмм": 1000000,
    "Сантиграмм": 10000,
    "Микрограмм": 1000000000,
    "Килотонна": 0.000001,
    "Ньютон на Земле": 9.81,
    "Карат": 5000,
    "Атомная масса": 1.66e-24,
    "Фунт": 2.20462,
    "Унция": 35.274,
    "Гран": 15432.4,
    "Стоун": 0.157473,
};
const os = document.querySelector('section')
const od = document.querySelector('template').content.querySelector('.line')
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    const o = od.cloneNode(true)
    o.querySelector('label').textContent = k
    o.querySelector('input').dataset.v = v
    os.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
})
os.addEventListener('input', e => {
    const ot = e.target
    let v = +ot.dataset.v
    v = +ot.value / v
    os.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(o => {
        if (o === ot) return
        o.value = +o.dataset.v * v
    })
})
```

```css
.line {
    display: flex;
}
.line label {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<template>
    <div class='line'>
        <label></label>
        <input type='number' />
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Вот у меня такая же проблема. Например если выполнить этот код и вести 1 Фунт, то он покажет 4.53592 килотонны, что не является истинной, разумеется)

Comment: @Sice60, я просто взял твои цифры... Очевидно что и `Фунт` у тебя определен не правильно.

Comment: @Sice60, проверил `Фунт` - все верно, 1кг это 2.2 фунта. Теперь про `килотонны` - `4.5359290943563973e-7`. Вот эта приписка в конце `e-7` тебе ни о чем не говорит? :) Это `0.00000045` килотонны!